# Is it possible to get commits from another user?

Tags: git, github

So my problem is that when I click the commits button in my repo some weird things happen, I have commits from another user, whom I searched in https://github.com/{the user} and nothing appeared, so the user doesn't exist and actually no one committed unless me.

Comment: May I clarify which system did you register your _click_ with? Git uses a username to associate commits with an identity and that name can be set using the `git config` command.

Comment: I didn't do the first-time setup, so If I do it now, it probably not going to change the name?

Comment: You may want to look at how to [amend the commit author]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi).

Answer (score 1):

Git uses a username to associate commits with an identity and that name can be set using the `git config` command.

Check your config to determine the username that is associated when you commit.

If you want to change it for commits that have already been committed, you may want to look at how to [amend the commit author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi).